# Is Tcpclient/Tcplistner class any faster than socket class

Tags: .net

My application is written in .net and runs over windows server. It connects over TCP/IP with a remote server and keep on listening. It sends only one message at the beginning of the connection which is a login message and thereafter it never send any message but just listen from the server. Its a stream socket and packets keep on coming quite frequently , about 6000 packets of size varying from 60 bytes to 200 bytes comes. So far I am using socket class and connects to the remote server. After sending log in request I start receving the stream on a continous basis. To receive the flow I am using BeginReceive, socketflags none. And after every beginreceive it repeats the task. Is there any other way to receive the stream in a faster way. My application is real time and very very time critical. Even 1 microsecond matters. Can anyone Suggest.

Comment: It would help to show more code; what does your receive loop look like?

Comment: Unless the server program is on the same computer, or on a local very high speed network, the network latencies are making microsecond resolution useless.

Answer (score 2):

`TcpClient` is simply a wrapper *on top of* a `Socket` and `NetworkStream`. It will not run *faster* - it is simply a different (more convenient) API. Additionally, as Joachim notes - this is unlikely to be a real bottleneck.

Some ideas you might try:

- if using the `NetworkStream` API, check `DataAvailable`, which indicates if there is data buffered; if there is, then try processing **sync** (via a few `Read`) until `DataAvailable` is false, at which point switch to *async** (`BeginRead`)
- separate the steps of buffering messages vs processing messages - your computer most likely has more than one core, and a separate read-loop/process-queue may increase throughput; you could also consider *parallel* processing threads, but that is more complex

When dealing with a remote server, "Even 1 microsecond matters" is simply infeasible. At that level, you would also want to be working crazy on garbage collection, perhaps looking at `struct` usage (passing via `ref`), which is very different to using `class`, and cannot be changed via a flat swap. And object pooling, etc. Very tricky.